# "Put a spoke in sb's wheel" Vs "Throw/put a (monkey) wrench in the works"

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

The English expressions:

> - throw a spanner in the works
>
>   - put a spanner in the works
>   - throw a (monkey) wrench in the works

**Mean:** to do something that prevents a plan or activity from succeeding: 
**Example:** The funding for the project was withdrawn so that really threw a spanner in the works.

and also:

> - To put a spoke in someone's wheel 
>     **Meaning:** to make it difficult for someone to achieve something they had planned to do 
>     **Example** - His letter really put a spoke in our wheel.

**My questions:**

**1)** Based on all the mentioned explanations, these four expressions mean so close that I cannot distinguish them. I wonder if you could give me a hand to differentiate between them.

**2)** Is it normal if I use **throw a spanner in the works** regarding a specific person and say: **throw a spanner in [someone's] works** or **throw a spanner in the works of [someone]**?

**3)** I would be appreciative if you could also help me to regionally devide them so that I discover which one is widespread in which country (AE and BE.

Comment: If *sb's* means *somebody's*, please spell out the full word.

Comment: I'm sorry @Jason Bassford. I will do my best.

Answer (score 2):

1) As you mentioned, all of these statement are very close in meaning to each other. A slight difference in meaning I see is that while 'putting a spoke in his (or their) wheel' always indicates interfering with the plans of someone else, 'putting a monkey wrench/spanner in the works' means that you are fouling up a particular system but not always the plans of someone else. Fouling up a system may also mess with the plans of whoever cares about that system, so the meanings can be the same, but if for example you threw a wrench into the works of a system that was malfunctioning or out of control, you may not be messing up the plans of anyone else.

2) Normal usage is 'throwing a spanner/monkey wrench in the works' when you are messing up a system and 'putting a spoke in his wheel' when messing up someone's plans.

3) 'Spanner' is the UK/British English term for what Americans call a 'Wrench'. A monkey wrench is a specific type of adjustable wrench, often referred to as a 'pipe wrench')